# Learning more advanced JavaScript

Tags: javascript

For learning JavaScript, I am following the w3schools website.

Can anybody provide me more effective learning site?

Comment: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: @swapnesh: I have already learned basic JS. Can you please provide me some link so that I can learn more advanced topic?

Comment: Best is go through the tag wiki http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Comment: many many thanks AurA

Comment: Can anybody refer me a good book for JS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[John Resig's tutorial](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/) and [Douglas Crockford's series](http://javascript.crockford.com/) are a probably a good start.

IMO you should also run away from w3schools as fast as you can [because](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: This is a very old post, but the link Douglas Crockford's series is dead. Here's an updated one: http://javascript.crockford.com/

Comment: @stfnnew: Thanks, I edited the answer to include your link.

Comment: +1 for Jon's suggestions. After 1.5 year of JavaScript experience, I get to know these are the good references.

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript Links to Js tutorials for Introductory, Intermediate and Advanced Levels

Comment: that link is also helpful. thanks